# Mysql query with join, limit and order is very slow (filesort)

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
explain select * from users, dls where dls.user_id=users.id and users.status = 'accepted' and users.acc = 0 order by users.user_name desc limit 18416, 16
```

Which results in the following explain;

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys          | key         | key_len | ref                             | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dls   | ALL  | PRIMARY,user_id         | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                            | 19910 | Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users  | ref  | PRIMARY,id_user_name | id_user_name | 4       | dls.user_id |     1 | Using where                     | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This query is really, really slow and I cannot figure out how to fix it. I tried all kinds of indexes from reading articles on how to optimize order by / limit queries, but the result remains the same. Can anyone please help?

Edit: schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (

  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_name` varchar(100) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
`status` enum('accepted','rejected') character set utf8 NOT NULL,
`acc` varchar(6) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
 KEY `id_user_name` (`id`,`user_name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `dls` (
 `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,

`download_url` varchar(255) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`category_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
)
```

Output for query by Scrummeister;

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+--------+---------+------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys          | key    | key_len | ref                          | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+--------+---------+------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u  | ALL  | PRIMARY,id_user_name | NULL   | NULL    | NULL                         | 10838 | Using where; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dls   | ref  | PRIMARY,user_id         | user_id | 4       | u.id |     2 |                             | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+--------+---------+------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Post also tables schemas. PS: `limit` with big offset is the weak side of mysql and cannot be optimized.

Comment: Added. Is there no way to make this faster while keeping the limit in tact? There are not really so many records yet...

Comment: Are you implementing paging, Otherwise how do you generate the `limit`?

Comment: Yes, it's paging showing 16 results / page.

Comment: Does removing the join and just selecting from the `users` table help?

Comment: How many rows are in the tables?

Comment: Yes, but then the limit is too high (so 0 results), but it's fast.

Comment: Can you please post the EXPLAIN output of this query `select STRAIGHT_JOIN * from users u JOIN dls ON dls.user_id=users.id where u.status = 'accepted' and u.acc = 0 order by users.user_name desc limit 18416, 16`

Comment: Is it any quicker/slower? Did you try increasing the `sort_buffer_size`?

Comment: Ah! It's much much faster. Can you tell me why? I never heard of straight join, but thank you very much for that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySql is known to have issues with a `LIMIT` using a large offset.

The [`STRAIGHT_JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) keyword, tells MySql to first scan the users table and then for every user, look up the rows in the `dls` table.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN *
FROM users u JOIN dls ON dls.user_id = users.id
WHERE u.status = 'accepted' and u.acc = 0
ORDER BY users.user_name desc 
LIMIT 18416, 16
```

Using STRAIGHT_JOIN is not recommended unless there is a need for it, In this specific case i believe it might work since it can use the `user_name` index for Sorting.

Other options you have:

- Increase the size of [`sort_buffer_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size)
- Increase the size of [`read_rnd_buffer_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_rnd_buffer_size) (with caution!)
- Doing the paging on the `users` table only, regardless of how many `dls` he has, Only than apply the `JOIN`.
- Handle the paging in your code. Assuming a user goes from page to page with skipping to many, you should store the first & last user names for each page. If the user clicks the next page - Add a `WHERE user_name > "{LastPageLastUsername} LIMIT 0,16"` this will increase

For other optimization, read [ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) and [Limit Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try add an index to the users table with the following columns

```
status, acc, user_name
```

or

```
acc, status, user_name
```

which ever is the faster

Comment: Adding a index starting with a small `enum` column leads to bad performance.

Comment: Could you explain why indexing an enum column would lead to bad performance? The index will allow the db engine locate the data using seeks which are far faster than scanning without an index.